# 98th call to pthread_create() fails

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm running the following program. It simply creates threads that die straight away.

What I have found is that after 93 to 98 (it varies slightly) successful calls, every next call to pthread_create() fails with error 11: Resource temporarily unavailable. I think I'm closing the thread correctly so it should give up on any resources it has but some resources become unavailable.

The first parameter of the program allows me to set the interval between calls to pthread_create() but testing with different values, I've learned that the interval does not matter (well, I'll get the error earlier): the number of successful calls will be the same.

The second parameter of the program allows me to set a sleep interval after a failed call but the length of the interval does not seem to make any difference.

Which ceiling am I hitting here?

EDIT: found the error in doSomething(): change lock to unlock and the program runs fine. The question remains: what resource is depleted with the error uncorrected?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

pthread_mutex_t doSomethingLock;

void milliSleep(unsigned int milliSeconds)
{
    struct timespec ts;

    ts.tv_sec = floorf(((float)milliSeconds / 1000));
    ts.tv_nsec = ((((float)milliSeconds / 1000) - ts.tv_sec)) * 1000000000;
    nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
}

void *doSomething(void *args)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    pthread_mutex_lock(&doSomethingLock);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t doSomethingThread;
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    int threadsCreated = 0;


    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: demo <interval between pthread_create() in ms> <time to wait after fail in ms>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP);
    pthread_mutex_init(&doSomethingLock, &attr);

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&doSomethingLock);
        if (pthread_create(&doSomethingThread, NULL, doSomething, NULL) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d pthread_create(): error %d, %m\n", threadsCreated, errno);
            milliSleep(atoi(argv[2]));
        }
        else threadsCreated++;
        milliSleep(atoi(argv[1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't really create 98 threads.

Comment: Really @H2CO3?  Since when is 98 threads a limit?  Java can to 10,000s.

Comment: I suspect you may be hitting ulimit restrictions.  I'd see if you can drop the stack size per thread or increase your allowable memory.

Comment: If you are creating that many threads, there's a good chance your program is badly designed. Nobody has 100-core processors, so the context-switching overhead will outweigh any benefit to parallelizing code to that degree.

Comment: I too suspect memory or address-space restrictions. Did you check the return value from pthread_detach() ?

Comment: @Gray Yes, really. I agree with Jonathan - your program must be badly designed if you need this. No, 98 is not a ultimate limit, but really, more of a dozen or two threads should always suffice. Please tell me which Java applications you wrote so I can avoid downloading them...

Comment: I write high performance web applications that handle millions of hits per day.  They aren't for download.  I'm just amazed that any thread platform has a limit of 100 threads in 2013.  It's amusing @H2CO3.

Comment: @Gray Maybe an enterprise server park can handle those requirements, but not a medium category PC...

Comment: I run my applications all of the time on my Mac desktop.  Maybe not 10000s of threads but for sure 1000s.  It's pretty amazing what the modern JVM/CPUs are capable of.  Cheers @H2CO3.

Comment: Oh and btw, the context-switching overhead is negligible these days -- at least in Java.  You see some drop-off but it's hard to thrash a box.  Believe me I've tried @JonathanGrynspan.  I used to think like that as well until I was showed data to the contrary.  It would be interesting to do that test in C-land.

Comment: Good for you. This is C, not Java.

Comment: 98 threads is nothing if most of them are blocked on I/O or each other.  My box has 1140 threads ATM.  Kaspersky has 104 on its own.

Comment: "*...I think I'm closing the thread correctly ...*" from the use of `doSomethingLock` I conclude no thread terminates, all are blocked in the call to `pthread_mutex_lock()`. Just an try out of the blue: How far do you get if you move `pthread_mutex_lock(&doSomethingLock);`out of the `while(1)` loop?

Comment: @alk I did expect that there would be an unlock somewhere, yes:)

Comment: Ok, I tested this on a rather small (1.5GB RAM) VM running a X86/64 Debian (stable) (hosted by win7) and made it up to 18551 threads ... (the top line: ` 2030 alk       20   0  145g 150m  532 S    9 12.8   0:17.89 main ` :-)

Comment: For the record, I just ran a small C program up through 10k threads each doing a billion arithmetic operations on a 4 processor system.  The timing from 30 iterations through 10k was pretty linear.  30 took 16 secs, 100 took 51, 300 took 154, 1000 took 512, 10000 took 5112.  So it looks like context switches are not an issue even at 10k threads @JonathanGrynspan.

Comment: @Gray Go back and read what I originally wrote. The benefit of running 100 threads in parallel is minimal because no user-level hardware can actually schedule that many threads in (true, real-world) parallel. The overhead of context switches, which is non-zero but which I never claimed was meaningfully high, would exceed any performance gained from that level of parallelism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on a 32 bit distro, you are probably hitting address space limits.   The last I checked, glibc will allocate about 13MB for stack space in every thread created (this is just the size of the mapping, not allocated memory).  With 98 threads, you will be pushing past a gigabyte of address space of the 3G available.

You can test this by freezing your process after the error (e.g. `sleep(1000000)` or whatever) and looking at its address space with `pmap`.

If that is the problem, then try setting a smaller stack size with `pthread_attr_setstack()` on the `pthread_attr_t` you pass to `pthread_create`.  You will have to be the judge of your stack requirements obviously, but often even complicated code can run successfully in only a few kilobytes of stack.

Comment: If the threads are exiting cleanly, the address space should be freed. which is why I wonder if pthread_detach is working.

Comment: @MarkR IIRC, `pthread_detach` does not cause a thread to exit (cleanly or otherwise), it just makes it not-joinable. I think the real issue is the attempt to `pthread_mutex_lock()` a mutex that the main thread is holding locked immediately after the `pthread_detach`, which prevents all the threads from progressing any further (oh, and possible address space exhaustion as mentioned in the above answer).

Comment: thanks Andy; that is probably the resource hitting its limit.

Answer (score 2):

Your program does not "*create threads that simply die away*". It does not do what you think it does.

First, `pthread_mutex_unlock()` only unlocks a `pthread_mutex_t` that has been locked *by the same thread*. This is how mutexes work: they can only be unlocked by the same thread that locked them. If you want the behaviour of a semaphore [semaphore](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), [use a semaphore](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html).

Your example code creates a recursive mutex, which the `doSomething()` function tries to lock. Because it is held by the original thread, it blocks (waits for the mutex to become free in the `pthread_mutex_lock()` call). Because the original thread never releases the lock, you just pile up new threads on top of the `doSomethingLock` mutex.

Recursivity with respect to mutexes just means a thread can lock it more than once; it must unlock it the same number of times for the mutex to be actually released.

If you change the `pthread_mutex_lock()` in `doSomething()` to `pthread_mutex_unlock()`, then you're trying to unlock a mutex not held by that thread. The call fails, and *then* the threads do die immediately.

---

Assuming you fix your program, you'll next find that you cannot create more than a hundred or so threads (depending on your system and available RAM).

The reason is well explained by Andy Ross: the fixed size stacks (`getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, (struct rlimit *)&info)` tells you how much, unless you set it via thread attributes) eat up your available address space.

The original stack given to the process is resized automatically, but for all other threads, the stack size is fixed. By default, it is very large; on my system, 8388608 bytes (8 megabytes).

I personally create threads with very small stacks, usually 65536 bytes, which is more than enough unless your functions use local arrays or large structures, or do insanely deep recursion:

```
#ifndef THREAD_STACK_SIZE
#define THREAD_STACK_SIZE  65536
#endif

pthread_attr_t   attrs;
pthread_t        thread[N];
int              i, result;

/* Create a thread attribute for the desired stack size. */
pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, THREAD_STACK_SIZE);

/* Create any number of threads.
 * The attributes are only a guide to pthread_create(),
 * they are not "consumed" by the call. */
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    result = pthread_create(&thread[i], &attrs, some_func, (void *)i);
    if (result) {
        /* strerror(result) describes the error */
        break;
    }
}

/* You should destroy the attributes when you know
 * you won't be creating any further threads anymore. */
pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);
```

The minimum stack size should be available as `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN`, and should be a multiple of `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`. Currently `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN == 16384`, but I recommend using a larger power of two. (Page sizes are *always* powers of two on any binary architecture.)

It is only the minimum, and the pthread library is free to use any larger value it sees fit, but in practice the stack size seems to be what you set it to, plus a fixed value depending on the architecture, kernel, and the pthread library version. Using a compile-time constant works well for almost all cases, but if your application is complex enough to have a configuration file, it might be a good idea to let the user override the compile-time constant if they want to, in the config file.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I have fixed my code and I'm trying to figure out how to set a reduced stack size of 64KB. Either pthread is ignoring my calls to pthread_attr_setstacksize() or getrlimit() is broken (it reports RLIM_INFINITY for rlim_cur and rlim_max), but I indeed do not get beyond 100 threads.